# Let $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ in probability such that $B \subset \{X_n = Y_n\}$ for all $n$. Is $B \setminus \{X=Y\}$ a null set?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a complete probability space. Let $X, Y, X_n, Y_n:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be random variables such that $X_n \to X$ in probability and $Y_n \to Y$ in probability. Let $B \in \mathcal F$ such that
$$
B \subset \{X_n = Y_n\} \quad \forall  n\in \mathbb N.
$$

> Is $B \setminus \{X=Y\}$ a null set?

**My attempt** We have
$$
\mathbb P [ B \setminus \{X=Y\} ] \subset \mathbb P [ \{X_n = Y_n\} \setminus \{X=Y\} ] = \mathbb E [1_{ \{X_n - Y_n =0\} \setminus \{X-Y=0\}}].
$$

Convergence in probability implies almost sure convergence of a subsequence. We assume $X_{n_k} \to X$ a.s. and $Y_{n_k} \to Y$ a.s. for some subsequence $(n_k)$. I don't know the point-wise convergence of $1_{ \{X_n - Y_n =0\} \setminus \{X-Y=0\}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists $(n_i)$ such that $X_{n_i} \to X$ a.s. and $Y_{n_i} \to Y$ a.s.  $B\setminus (X= Y)\subset \{X_{n_i}=Y_{n_i} \forall N, X\neq Y\}$ and this last event is a  null event.

Comment: We have $B\setminus \{X\neq Y\}\subset C:= \{X_{n_i} =  Y_{n_i} \, \forall i\} \setminus \{X\neq Y\}$. How do you get $C \subset \{X_{n_i} =  Y_{n_i} \, \forall i;X\neq Y\}$?

Comment: There was  a typo. @Analyst

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\{\omega : X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega)\} = \cup_k \{\omega : |X(\omega) - Y(\omega)| > 1/k\}$. So, if $P(B \setminus \{X = Y\}) > 2 \epsilon$, then also $B \setminus \{|X - Y| < 1/k\} > \epsilon$ for some $n$.

But as $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ in probability, for large enough $n$ we have $P(|X_n - X| > \frac{1}{3k}) < \epsilon / 3$ and $P(|Y_n - Y| > \frac{1}{3k}) < \epsilon / 3$.

Then we have
$$P(B \setminus \{|X - Y| < 1/k\}) =\\
P((B \cap \{X_n = Y_n\}) \setminus \{|X - Y| < 1/k\}) \leq\\
P(X_n = Y_n, |X - Y| > 1/k) \leq\\
P\left(|X_n - X| > \frac{1}{3k} \vee |Y_n - Y| > \frac{1}{3k}\right) \leq\\
\frac{2 \epsilon}{3} < \epsilon$$